# paplay: --volume option does not take effect

Tags: command-line, fedora, audio, pulseaudio, pipewire

I recently installed Fedora 36. I have a script that plays certain sound files.
The script was used under Ubuntu 20.04 before, showing the expected behaviour.

Inside the script, I use the following command:

```
paplay --volume=65536 -d alsa_output.pci-0000_33_00.6.HiFi__hw_Generic_1__sink ~/soundfiles/notification.wav
```

On Ubuntu, this led to the notification being played on maximum volume due to the `--volume=65536` setting, but since I switched to Fedora, this setting is no longer having any effect. No matter what value I give (even lower ones), the notification sound will always play with the current default system volume.

I tried with `canberra-gtk-play`, but that shows the same behaviour: no matter if I try `canberra-gtk-play -f ~/soundfiles/notification.wav --volume=5` or `canberra-gtk-play -f ~/soundfiles/notification.wav --volume=10`, the sound will always play on the default system volume level.

Anybody got any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue but found this [thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=283537), and switched to `pw-play`. I realized something like this snippet works as expected:

```
pw-play --volume=0.5 ~/soundfiles/notification.wav
```